# Resolving Unity dependencies in a Prism Desktop application

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

following a previous question I posted on StackOverFlow I have the following project structure to my Prism desktop application.

**Class Library** : *Application.Common* --> this contains all my DTOs and the service contracts that are defined in my WCF service layer which is an entirely different solution.

**Modules:** *Application.Modules.ServicesModule* --> in here I have added links to my WCF implementation using Add Service Reference. I also register the implementations of my types IMyServiceContract is defined in the Application.Common assembly so the initialise method looks as below:-

```
public void Initialise()
{
   _container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyServiceClient>(new InjectionConstructor());
}
```

Finally I have another module *Application.Modules.FunctionalityModule* this has a constructor defined as follows

```
   public FunctionalityModule(IMyService myService){}
```

when the application is trying to resolve the dependency in FunctionalityModule at runtime the following error occurs

```
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, AccountsSln.Common.ServiceContract.IMyService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

Normally, I have seen this error because a dependency has not been registered but on this occassion I know it has in the ServicesModule. Is this something to do with the registering being in different modules? Are there any other suggestions on how I can implement my project structure to support WCF services in a Prism desktop application?

Thanks

Alex

**Edit:**
As I wanted to use a Common assembly to define my service contracts I was having problems when using Add Service Reference. It turns out that if you use Add Service Reference the generated code uses the metadata to create client side types. These have the same signature as the ones in the Common assembly but are different. To enable me to use the contracts in the Common assembly I took inspiration from this post http://xaml.geek.nz/working-slightly-smarter-with-wcf. This got me started in the right direction but I think I will have to look into making the code more suited to a production environment.

Comment: Are you sure the ServicesModule is being loaded? And is it being loaded before the FunctionalityModule?

Comment: Yes if i breakpoint the Initialise in the ServicesModule it is definitely being hit. Also, the ServicesModule is before the FunctionalityModule in the Bootstrapper so I assume that means it is being loaded before.

Comment: Where is the _container instance coming from in the ServicesModule?  Is it being injected through its constructor or instantiated within the module?

Comment: It is being injected in the constructor of the ServicesModule.

Comment: The line `_container.RegisterType(IMyService, MyServiceContractClient)();` obviously doesn't compile. Can you show us the actual code so we'll be able to help you better?

Comment: @Lester, I have edited the code to show the actual code which does compile

Comment: I'm not sure if it has anything to do with your problem, but the `new InjectionConstructor()` seems pretty unneeded. I would use `_container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyServiceClient>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())` (assuming this service should exist as long as the container exists).

Comment: @Lester, I think one of my problems maybe that I have defined my IMyService operation contract in the Application.Common library and this is what the WCF service implements. However, when I use Add Service Reference it seems to use Application.Modules.ServicesModule.IMyService. This is not what I want to happen as I would like to define all my service contracts in a common assembly.

Comment: Also, if I do not use InjectionConstructor I get an error saying that InvalidOperationException - The type MyServiceClient has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not specified the required mapping from the interface to the implementation type. (I prefer using `UnityContainerExtensions`).

```
unityContainer.RegisterType < IStudentSearchService, StudentSearchService > ();
```

You also need to specify module dependencies. Your `FunctionalityModule` is dependent on the `ServicesModule`. How this is accomplished depends on how the `ModuleCatalog` is created.
So either; in Bootstrapper's `CreateModuleCatalog` use `moduleCatalog.AddModule`, or decorating the `IModules` with `ModuleAttribute` and `ModuleDependencyAttribute` if using the `DirectoryModuleCatalog`.

Of course the `UnityContainer` can be configured through the app.config file.

Comment: I believe that I have added the mapping. What I have noticed is that if I add ServiceReference I have to make the interface side of the mapping come from  Application.Modules.ServicesModule for it to work. It does not work if I take the interface side of the mapping from  Application.Common which is where I want to take it from and is also what is defined as my interface in the actual WCF implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The generated service proxy classes are partial classes.  You might be able to just make them inherit from the `IMyService` in the Common assembly, by adding something like following in the project where the service references are:

```
using Application.Common.IMyService;

namespace Application.Modules.ServicesModule
{
    public partial class MyServiceClient : Application.Common.IMyService
    {
    }
}
```